# Unable to complete Trello authentication

Tags: python, trello, trelloapi

I work on Trello API integration in my project. When I start the authentication process then I get one URL like this(https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=). After that, I need to click on Allow button and get an access token manually and set it into the Python backend. So is there any way to get an access token without an interaction browser? If yes then please let me know how can I complete this task.

I use these three URLs in my code.

```
request_token_url = 'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken'
authorize_url = 'https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken'
access_token_url = 'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken'
```